# DrawerLayout not clickable after Fragment load

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I followed the android guideline and completed a layout looks like this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id= "@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/wall"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IGuessI'mUsername?"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_item"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/side_item_home"
                android:text="Home"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_home"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Activities"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/side_item_activities"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_search_holo_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/side_item_settings"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

FYI, I did not use `Android.R.Id`, but my own `R.id.fragmentContainer` to load the fragments. But apparently, the drawer layout is under the fragment loaded in the FrameLayout. If I click the item on the DrawerLayout, the fragments receive the gesture, not the DrawerLayout, although it still display correctly.

I need your two cents, guys. All answers and comments are appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is the requested code.

```
public class ClipMe_main extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;
    SlidingTabFragment homeFragment;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mTitle;
    Fragment settingsFragment;
    private ArrayList<DrawerItemModel> drawerData;
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    public static DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    int visiblePage;
    TextView sideBarHome;
    TextView sideBarActivities;
    TextView sideBarSettings;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_activity);
        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        registerReceiver(receiverDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadService.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        sideBarHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.side_item_home);
        sideBarActivities = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.side_item_activities);
        sideBarSettings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.side_item_settings);
        sideBarSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
        sideBarHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        sideBarActivities.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                new Toolbar(ClipMe_main.this),
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
            }
        };

        setUpView();
        setUpHomeFragment();
        setUpSettingFragment();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.swipe_refresh_2));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        bar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    }

    private void setUpSettingFragment() {
        settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    }

    void setUpView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_activity);

    }

    void setUpHomeFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        homeFragment = new SlidingTabFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, homeFragment, "home");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment, boolean shouldAnimate) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        if (shouldAnimate)
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        Log.d("FragmentManager", "Push " + tag);
    }


    public void getFragmentAndUpdate(int page) {
        PopularFragment currentFragment = homeFragment.getCurrentFragment();
        currentFragment.requestMoreData(page);
        Log.d("FragmentPage", String.valueOf(page));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_clipme_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public int findVisibleFragment(){
        Fragment homeFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("home");
        Fragment activitiesFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("activities");
        Fragment settingsFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("settings");
        Fragment likeFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("like");
        Fragment commentFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("comment");

        if(homeFragment!= null && homeFragment.isVisible()){
            return 1;
        } else if(activitiesFragment!= null && activitiesFragment.isVisible()){
            return 2;
        } else if (settingsFragment!= null && settingsFragment.isVisible()){
            return 3;
        } else if (likeFragment!= null && likeFragment.isVisible()){
            return 4;
        } else if (commentFragment!= null && commentFragment.isVisible()){
            return 5;
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == sideBarHome){
            if (findVisibleFragment() == 1){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                pushFragments("activities", homeFragment, true);
            }
        }
        if (v == sideBarActivities){
            if (findVisibleFragment() == 2){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                pushFragments("activities", new ActivitiesFragment(), true);
            }
        }
        if (v == sideBarSettings){
            if (findVisibleFragment() == 1){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                pushFragments("activities", settingsFragment, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code where you are adding fragment in activity and the navigationdrawer click part.

Comment: @droidkid I have added the code you requested.

Comment: while clicking the drawer...you able to load your fragment(able to see)

Comment: Actually no, that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: OK, Try to comment the 'if' conditions in the onClick() method. Just put the pushFragments() line

Comment: your navigation code is correct and i think the issue is with the onClick if() logic

Comment: I added debug at the OnClick, and it's not even detecting. Well, the gesture is sent to the fragment below, actually.

Comment: 'gesture is sent' means??

Comment: That mean that the Onclicklistener in the default fragment in the FragmentContainer receive the click (and scrolling gesture), but not the DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i found is in the onClick() method. Try changing the function as below

```
public Fragment findVisibleFragment() {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        return fragment;
}
```

Edit:

set the same listener to multiple views.

```
sideBarHome.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
sideBarSettings.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Refer this clicklistener object to the view and you can use the same logic to differentiate views

```
 View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.side_item_home) {
//            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                if (!(findVisibleFragment() instanceof SlidingTabFragment)) {
                    pushFragments("activities", homeFragment, true);
                }
            }
            else if() {
                //rest click logic
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I have just tried your answer, but the problem is still there. The Drawer is unclickable, as the clickEvent is caught by the `Viewpager SwipeRefreshLayout` in the FragmentContainer. I guess I'll try to write it all again.

Comment: what viewpager??wher is that?....how could i help you without having those things in your code.

Comment: Actually the code is really long, so I'll just brief it here:
I have a FragmentContainer which has the default SlidingTabLayout. The slidingTabLayout use a viewpager to slide to 3 different Fragment, on all of which have a onClickListener. When the onClickListener on DrawerLayout is clicked, the Fragment OnclickListener fires.

Comment: There you might be using getActivity() to setlistener. Try   view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });
in your activity and fragment